# DB sets in Context are not connected between eachother

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a SQL Server database and an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC project. In this project I scaffolded a context and model classes to work with the database.

They look like this:

```
public partial class Character
{
        public Character()
        {
            Battles = new HashSet<Battle>();
            CharactersInDungeons = new HashSet<CharactersInDungeon>();
            CharactersWeapons = new HashSet<CharactersWeapon>();
        }
        
        [DisplayName("Имя")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        [DisplayName("Уровень")]
        public int? Level { get; set; }
        
        [DisplayName("Здоровье")]
        public int? Health { get; set; }
        
        [DisplayName("Сила атаки")]
        public int? Attack { get; set; }
        
        [DisplayName("Класс")]
        public string Class { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Battle> Battles { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CharactersInDungeon> CharactersInDungeons { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CharactersWeapon> CharactersWeapons { get; set; }
} 

public class Battle
{
        [DisplayName("Имя персонажа")]
        public string CharacterName { get; set; }
        
        [DisplayName("Название монстра")]
        public string MonsterName { get; set; }
        
        [DisplayName("Название оружия")]
        public string WeaponName { get; set; }

        public virtual Character CharacterNameNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual Monster MonsterNameNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual Weapon WeaponNameNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

The character class connected with some other, like Battle, for example, but when I try to get all battles of some character in controller, there is nothing, count of the battles = 0. But when I debugging it and expand every DBSet in my context like this when the program is in some action:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O69po.png

All the connections between the tables appear and the count of battles of the character is not zero anymore.

How can I get permanent connection between tables in my context without debugging?

**upd:** I try to get battles of some character like this:

```
List<Battle> battles= new List<Battle>();

var character = await _context.Characters.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Name == id);

foreach (var battle in character.Battles)
{
    battles.Add(battle);
}
```

As you can see, The character should have a link to all battles within him.And it should look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fN87.png

There are 3 battles of the character named Antoswka240. On the other hand, the battle has a link to Antoswka240.

Comment: Show us the code that attempts to *get all battles of some character*? I would expect perhaps `context.Characters.Include(c => c.Battles).Find("joely moely")`

Comment: (Or if you mention Battles in a Select you don't have to include as EF will do it implicitly eg if you did `context.Characters.Where(c => c.Age < 27).Select(c => new { c.Name, c.Battles } );`